# need assistance for database input

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

hey there I did a pdo registry system - but I used three classes instead - but I am not getting it to insert the email/password into the registry - it just enters a blank screen, no input.

So here are the code for the 3 classes below:

**connect.php**

```
<?php
class Connect{
  public function dbConnex(){
    return new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=demodatabase", "root","password");
  }
}
?>
```

**Header.php**

```
<?php
include_once('Connect.php');
class Header{
  public $odb;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->odb = new Connect();
    $this->odb = $this->db->dbConnex();
  }

  public function Register($first_name, $last_name, $email_id, $password){
    if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){
      $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
      $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
      $email_id = $_POST['email_id'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      $q = "INSERT INTO demoregi(first_name, last_name, email_id, password) VALUES(:first_name, :last_name, :email_id, :password);";
      $query = $odb->prepare($q);
      $results =    $query->execute(array(
            ":first_name" => $first_name,
            ":last_name" => $last_name,
            ":email_id" => $email_id,
            ":password" => $password
      ));
    }
  } 
}   
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
include_once('Header.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $first_name= $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email_id = $_POST['email_id'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $object = new Header();
    $object -> Register($first_name, $last_name,$email_id,$password);
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="header.php">
        <br>First Name: <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"/></br>
        <br>Last Name: <input type="text" id= "last_name" name="last_name"/></br>
        <br>Email: <input type="text" id="email_id" name="email_id"/></br>
        <br>Password: <input type="password" id= "password" name="password"/></br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

so how do I get it to input data into the database? I get NO error messages - just a blank screen that the register button redirects me to.

Simple solution to the problem. Would like some help! Thanks a million!!!

Comment: You need to use ` $query = $this->odb->prepare($q);`, otherwise your database handle is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to point out.

1. your form redirects your page to header.php when your code for submitting the form is on index.php (Which i believe to be the main issue here. Then you probably will end up with errors)
2. In your Class Header. The function Register has $first_name, $last_name, $email_id, $password passed to them so why are you resetting the values of $first_name with $_POST['first_name'] when this was passed into the class

Comment: try and catch has nothing to do with throwing exceptions, mind you

Comment: @YourCommonSense however if you are marking me down for that then maybe you should the other post as they also have used $odb->errorInfo()

Answer (score 0):

I see many big mistakes.

1st. in your index.php you are doing :

```
$first_name= $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email_id = $_POST['email_id'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$object = new Header();
$object -> Register($first_name, $last_name,$email_id,$password);
```

Then you do it all over again :

```
 public function Register($first_name, $last_name, $email_id, $password){
     if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){
    
     first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
     $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
     $email_id = $_POST['email_id'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     // other stuff
```

You shouldn't rely on $_POST or $_GET in your function as you're

1. already asking in the parameter what you need.
2. lying to your function about what it really needs. Never rely on super global to complete your function.

Second I suggest you use [PDO::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to bind your values.

Then, what you should do is tell us what error you get! it could be anything from wrong column name to a simple typo. To do this do :

```
var_dump($odb->errorInfo());
```